Fill first (only one) NA with next non-NA value by group using dplyr/tidyr
I hava a problem, where I need to fill NA by group, but only one (the first) NA before some non-NA value (direction = "up"). I know the tidyr fill() function but do not know how to use it conditionally (so to fill only one NA above some non-NA value).
df <- data.frame(g=c(1,1,1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,2,2,2,2),v=c(NA,NA,5,NA,8,NA, 1,1,NA,2,NA,NA,3))

Data (with group "g" and values "v"):
   g  v
1  1 NA
2  1 NA
3  1  5
4  1 NA
5  1  8
6  1 NA
7  2  1
8  2  1
9  2 NA
10 2  2
11 2 NA
12 2 NA
13 2  3

should become...
   g  v
1  1 NA
2  1  5
3  1  5
4  1  8
5  1  8
6  1 NA
7  2  1
8  2  1
9  2  2
10 2  2
11 2 NA
12 2  3
13 2  3


You can always create your own solution:
fill_one_up <- \(x) {
  n <- length(x)
  if (n <= 1L) return(x)
  for (i in 2L:n) {
    if (!is.na(x[i]) && is.na(x[i-1L])) {
      x[i-1L] <- x[i]
    }
  }
  return(x)
}

df <- df |> mutate(v2 = fill_one_up(v), .by=g)

#    g  v v2
# 1  1 NA NA
# 2  1 NA  5
# 3  1  5  5
# 4  1 NA  8
# 5  1  8  8
# 6  1 NA NA
# 7  2  1  1
# 8  2  1  1
# 9  2 NA  2
# 10 2  2  2
# 11 2 NA NA
# 12 2 NA  3
# 13 2  3  3

If you need more speed you can translate the logic to Rcpp:
Rcpp::cppFunction("NumericVector fill_one_up_cpp(NumericVector x) {
  int n = x.size();
  if (n <= 1) return x;
  for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    if (ISNA(x[i-1]) && !ISNA(x[i])) {
      x[i-1] = x[i];
    }
  }
  return x;
}")

EDIT
Using ThomasIsCoding's idea to first locate all the NAs fill_one_up() can be further simplified:
fill_one_up2 <- \(x) {
  idx <- which(is.na(x))
  idx <- idx[which(!is.na(x[idx + 1]))]
  x[idx] <- x[idx+1]
  x
} 

Which seems can be made faster with collapse:
library(collapse)
fill_one_up4 <- \(x) {
  idx <- whichNA(x)
  idx <- fsubset(idx, whichNA(x[idx + 1], TRUE))
  copyv(x, idx, R = x[idx+1], vind1 = TRUE) # Could play with setv() with care
}


Oh wow... thank you! This seems to be way faster than using the "lead" function as in Thomas' solution :-O

I accept this answer due to better performance.

if you want to accelerate the code, you can simplify the process by focusing on NAs and there next values only, which should save a lot of time (see ftic1 in my updated answer). You can of course use Rcpp with the similar idea.

nice @ThomasIsCoding! Actually with that logic you can avoid the loop altogether

You can try coalesce + lead
> df %>%
+     mutate(vv = coalesce(v, lead(v)), .by = g)
   g  v vv
1  1 NA NA
2  1 NA  5
3  1  5  5
4  1 NA  8
5  1  8  8
6  1 NA NA
7  2  1  1
8  2  1  1
9  2 NA  2
10 2  2  2
11 2 NA NA
12 2 NA  3
13 2  3  3


With base R, you can define a customize a function f like below and then use ave to update the values by groups
f <- function(x) {
    idx <- which(is.na(x))
    p <- x[idx + 1]
    for (i in seq_along(idx)) {
        if (!is.na(p[i])) {
            x[idx[i]] <- p[i]
        }
    }
    x
}

and you will obtain
> transform(df, vv = ave(v, g, FUN = f))
   g  v vv
1  1 NA NA
2  1 NA  5
3  1  5  5
4  1 NA  8
5  1  8  8
6  1 NA NA
7  2  1  1
8  2  1  1
9  2 NA  2
10 2  2  2
11 2 NA NA
12 2 NA  3
13 2  3  3

Benchmarking
ftic0 <- function() {
    df %>%
        mutate(vv = coalesce(v, lead(v)), .by = g)
}

ftic1 <- function() {
    f <- function(x) {
        idx <- which(is.na(x))
        p <- x[idx + 1]
        for (i in seq_along(idx)) {
            if (!is.na(p[i])) {
                x[idx[i]] <- p[i]
            }
        }
        x
    }

    transform(df, vv = ave(v, g, FUN = f))
}

fsbaldur0 <- function() {
    fill_one_up <- \(x) {
        n <- length(x)
        if (n <= 1L) {
            return(x)
        }
        for (i in 2L:n) {
            if (!is.na(x[i]) && is.na(x[i - 1L])) {
                x[i - 1L] <- x[i]
            }
        }
        return(x)
    }
    df |> mutate(vv = fill_one_up(v), .by = g)
}

fsbaldur1 <- function() {
    setDT(df)[, vv := fcoalesce(v, shift(v, -1)), by = g]
    setDF(df)
}

microbenchmark(
    ftic0 = ftic0(),
    ftic1 = ftic1(),
    fsbaldur0 = fsbaldur0(),
    fsbaldur1 = fsbaldur1(),
    unit = "relative",
    check = "equivalent"
)

shows
Unit: relative
      expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
     ftic0 8.920659 6.457389 6.810327 5.939112 6.231513 10.436721   100
     ftic1 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000  1.000000   100
 fsbaldur0 6.199669 4.508141 4.460354 4.107098 4.139735  3.520242   100
 fsbaldur1 2.614049 2.188928 2.375262 2.137102 2.232717  5.698269   100


Thank you, nice and clean! The lead function seems to be a little slow on my "largeish" dataset. However, I guess this is the price to pay... Thanks again...

@Peter You can use the same logic with data.table. setDT(df)[,  vv := fcoalesce(v, shift(v, -1)), by = g]; setDF(df)

@s_baldur yes, thanks for contributing the data.table approach.

@Peter yes, the only benefit I saw from that code is the conciseness. You can take a look at the updated solutions and benchmarking if speed is your concern.

in f() we already know that is.na(x[idx[i]]) evaluates to True.

@s_baldur yes, you are right! thanks for helping to improve the code.
